# Writting a file with german letters like ü ,ä, ö and ß in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating files with this function in python 2

```
 with io.FileIO(station_data['name']+".pls", "w") as file:
       file.write("[playlist] " + \n + "numberofentries=1" + \n + "File1=" + station_data['streamURL'] + \n + "Title1=" + station_data['name'] )
```

But when in station_[name] is an "Ä" or "Ü" and so on, I get this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't enconde character u'\xfc' in position 171: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the whole script

```
import requests
import sys
import os
import json
import io
from objbrowser import browse

class RadioStations():
  user_agent = {'User-agent': 'User-Agent: XBMC Addon Radio'}
  data = []
  no_data = True
  url = "http://radio.de/info/menu/broadcastsofcategory?category=_top"
  try:
    response  = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
    data = response.json()
    no_data = False
    print("Data found")
  except requests.HTTPError, e:
    print("HTTP error %s", e.code)
    no_data = False
  except requests.ConnectionError, e:
    data.append({'name': 'no station data'}) 
    no_data = True
    print("Connection error %s", e)
  print("Getting StreamUrls and creating files")
  for item in data:
     id2 = str(item['id'])
     url = "http://radio.de/info/broadcast/getbroadcastembedded?broadcast=" + id2
     response = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
     station_data = response.json()
     with open("{}.pls".format(station_data['name']).encode('utf-8'), "wb") as file:
       txt = "[playlist]\nnumberofentries=1\nFile1={}\nTitle1={}".format(station_data['streamURL'],station_data['name'])
       file.write(txt)
     if "errorCode" in station_data.keys():
       print("no such entry")

  print("Finished")
```

It is based on this script on [GitHub](https://github.com/mottobug/mp3pi/blob/master/radiostations.py)

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.x as it deals with Unicode much better than Python 2.x.

Comment: this is not valid python.

Comment: `"{}.pls".format(station_data['name']).encode('utf-8')`, no, please no, not even in Python 2. And this does not work, either, since to-string conversion now happens still during the format. `open()` accepts [unicode filenames](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames) and converts them to the filesystem encoding as necessary. Using `u"{}.pls".format(station_data['name'])` should fix your problem. And as a reminder: You absolutely need to watch out when mixing strings and unicode in Python 2.

Comment: @dhke this gets the error to this line `file.write(txt)`

Comment: @Krishkat Same problem. If `station_data` contains unicode, `"".format()` coerces it to the default encoding. Have a look at [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open). But more important: Go through your code and check your string types. Don't rely on Python2's unicode automagic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(u"{}.pls".format(station_data['name']), "wb") as file:
       txt = u"[playlist]\nnumberofentries=1\nFile1={}\nTitle1={}".format(station_data['streamURL'],station_data['name']).encode('utf-8')
       file.write(txt)
```

It works with this variant which is combined of your answers

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is open the file as `wb` which will write to file in binary mode. That way you can write non-ascii characters to files, and why not just use the open() command? 
And as a tip, use string formatting to make your script look neater.

```
with open("{}.pls".format(station_data['name']).encode('utf-8'), "wb") as file:
   txt = "[playlist]\nnumberofentries=1\nFile1={}\nTitle1={}".format(station_data['streamURL'],station_data['name'])
   file.write(txt) # don't forget to encode it if you're on Python 3
```

For python 2, you don't need to `.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: well this doesn't work because the error comes in `with open("{}.pls".format(station_data['name']), "wb") as file:`

Comment: It shouldn't have any problem, what did you type and what exactly is  station_data['name']. Make sure your string is not prepended with `u`

Comment: @Krishkat If it is, do `station_data['name'].encode('utf-8')` instead

Comment: that is my station_data['name'] u'SWR1 Baden-W\xfcrttemberg'

Comment: When I use this code `sname = station_data['name'].encode('utf-8')
     with open(sname+'.pls', "wb") as file:
       txt = "[playlist]\nnumberofentries=1\nFile1={}\nTitle1={}".format(station_data['streamURL'],sname)
       file.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))` I get an error in `file.write`: can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 169

Comment: still doesn't work I updatet my question to give more information

Comment: `"{}.pls".format(station_data['name'])`. Assuming `station_data['name']` is unicode, you might get the conversion error right there during format. `open()` happily accepts unicode filenames and converts them using the filesystem encoding. If you really need to to it manually, use `u"{}.pls".format(...).encode(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import sys

fname = "RöckDöts!"
efname = fname.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
open(efname, 'w')
```

See if that works.

Comment: it doesn't work, I stil get the same error. I combined your answers `sname = station_data['name']
     efname = sname.encode('utf-8')
     with open(efname+'.pls', "wb") as file:
       txt = "[playlist]\nnumberofentries=1\nFile1={}\nTitle1={}".format(station_data['streamURL'],sname)
       file.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))` but it doesn't work, too

Comment: What if you `print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())`? What does that say?